# Compile-time calculation of bits needed to represent a range

Tags: c++, c++11, compile-time

I need to calculate at compile-time the number of bits needed to represent a range. 
For an unsigned range from 0 to n it is simple:

```
constexpr unsigned bits_to_represent(uintmax_t n) 
{
    return n > 0 
        ? 1 + bits_to_represent(n/2)
        : 0; 
}
```

For a signed range, I have:

```
constexpr unsigned bits_in_range(intmax_t min,intmax_t max)
{
    return bits_to_represent(max >= 0
              ? static_cast<uintmax_t>(max) - min
              : max - min);
}
```

However this causes MSVC 2015 (recently updated) to complain:

warning C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type

Can you explain why this happens? As a work-around, I static_cast min to uintmax_t, but I do not like this solution as it seems less portable than my preferred solution and probably even is undefined behaviour, even though I am sceptical is that can happen at compile time.

Comment: Can you show the code that calls `bits_in_range`? If `min > max` then I would expect this warning, so maybe it's a simple mistake.

Comment: Sorry - should have mentioned that min <= max always. I get this warning e.g. for bits_in_range(-6,700).

Comment: What line does the error appear on?

Comment: I had the warning on the line static_cast<uint_max_t>(max) - min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why MSVC is giving a warning, but one thing that you are doing that could cause bad behavior is mixing signed and unsigned integers in arithmetic operations and comparisons.

You can read this for examples of problems caused by this: http://blog.regehr.org/archives/268

I would try rewriting your function like this:

```
constexpr unsigned bits_in_range(intmax_t min,intmax_t max)
{
    return bits_to_represent(
             static_cast<uintmax_t>(max) - static_cast<uintmax_t>(min));
}
```

This way is more programmer friendly. When you do arithmetic operations on mismatched integer types, the compiler is going to have to do implicit conversions to make them match. This way, it doesn't have to do that. Even if max and min are negative, this will still give well-defined and correct results, if you are sure that `max >= min`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in 4 parts.  Each of min max at least zero.

If they share the same sign (with 0 as positive), 2s complement integers can have their difference represented as part of their own type.

That leaves `max<min` and `max` positive and `min` negative cases.

If we assume `uint_max_t` is big enough, arithmetic and conversion to that type all behaves according to math mod `2^n`.

So `unsigned(a)-unsigned(b)` will actually be the unsigned distance to get from b to a as signed integers.

```
C = A-B mod X
C = A-B + kX
B+C=A+kX
```

With `C` positive and less than `X`, and `X` larger than `B-A`, gives us `C` must be the delta.

Comment: Sorry - should have mentioned that my algorithm requires min <= max, the functions are only called when this requirement is satisfied. The solution you propose (casting the negative min to an unsigned value) is exactly the solution outlined in my question. The problem is that I do not like that solution as this seems less portable. Perhaps I am pedantic, but I do not find this cast that well defined.

Comment: @user I described why it was well defined.

Comment: That is correct, you told me - but just did not quite convince me. ;-) But you are right of course and I should have known how conversion from signed to unsigned works in C++. Actually - assuming as I did - that min <= max, the calculation is even simpler. See my answer to my own post.

Comment: You need to better define your allowed input values to `bits_in_range`. For example, if you allow negative values for min then someone can pass in `-1` for `min` and `INTMAX_MAX` for `max` and now the range you need to represent is going to be larger than intmax_t can represent, so subtracting those values will wrap and hence be UD.

Comment: @bee In the max positive and min negative, you convert both to unsigned.  This is defined behaviour.  You subtract them as unsigned.  This is defined behaviour.  My argument above then demonstrates that the result is the mathematical distance between them as integers.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments even though they did not explain the Microsoft warning. Clang compiles cleanly, so it might be a bug in the compiler.
Due to the nature of conversion from signed to unsigned values in C++ the correct answer will be obtained by simply casting both values (again assuming that min <= max):

```
constexpr unsigned bits_in_range(intmax_t min,intmax_t max)
{
    return bits_to_represent(static_cast<largest_uint>(max) -
                             static_cast<largest_uint>(min));
}
```

The validity of the code can be inferred from this part of the draft standard (I looked at the newest draft but am confident that there has not been a change here).

> 4.7 Integral conversions [conv.integral]
>
> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least > unsigned integer congruent to the source
>   integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the
>   unsigned type).